# What is the implicit resolution chain of `<:<`

Tags: scala

The compiler is able to provide evidence about type parameters, e.g:

```
def foo[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B): B
```

A look at the type definition for `<:<` in `Predef` shows

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
private[this] final val singleton_<:< = new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]
```

1. Can anyone explain the implicit resolution chain here? How can `$conforms[A]: A <:< A` convince the compiler to create an instance of `<:<[List[String], Seq[String]]` for instance? Or `<:<[Dog, Animal]`. And what happens if (when) the `.asInstanceOf` call throws an exception?
2. Why is the subclassing of `=>` necessary?

Comment: It's the variance on the `<:<` class that enables it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the `scala.Predef` object: https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native/blob/master/scalalib/overrides-2.11/scala/Predef.scala#L372

```
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${From} <:< ${To}.")
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable

private[this] lazy val singleton_<:< = new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
@inline implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]

@deprecated("Use `implicitly[T <:< U]` or `identity` instead.", "2.11.0")
def conforms[A]: A <:< A = $conforms[A]
```

`<:<[-From, +To]` contravariant over `Form` and covariant over `To`, hence `<:<[Seq[String], Seq[String]]` is a subtype of `<:<[List[String], Seq[String]]` (because `List[String]` is a subtype of `Seq[String]` and `-From` is contravariant). So, when you write `implicit ev List[String] <:< Seq[String]` the compiler use `<:<[Seq[String], Seq[String]]`

When you write `implicit ev T <:< D` and there is no `A` that conforms `T <: A <: D`, the compiler doesn't compile it, because there is no `<:<[A, A]` that conforms `<:<[A, A] <: <:<[T, D]`. So, `.asInstanceOf` never throws an exception inside `$conforms` in runtime.

Also, a very good blog post about it: http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html