# In scala 3, is it possible to make covariant/contravariant type constructor to honour coercive subtyping?

Tags: scala, types, implicit, upcasting, type-coercion

This is a simple example:

```scala
object CoerciveCovariance {

  trait Cov[+T]

  def cast[A, B](v: Cov[A])(
      implicit
      ev: A <:< B
  ) = {
    v: Cov[B]
  }
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
CoerciveCovariance.scala:11:5: Found:    (v : xxx.CoerciveCovariance.Cov[A])
Required: xxx.CoerciveCovariance.Cov[B]
one error found
```

Is it very hard to make to compiler to figure out the missing coercive upcasting from `Cov[A]` to `Cov[B]`? Why is it not the default behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because type inference and implicit resolution are different. `<:` and `+` belong to type inference, `<:<` belongs to implicit resolution.

They make impact to each other. Indeed, type inference makes impact to implicit resolution

```
trait TC[A]
implicit val int: TC[Int] = null

def foo[A](a: A)(implicit tc: TC[A]) = null
foo(1) // compiles
foo("a") // doesn't compile
```

Here firstly type `A` is inferred to be `Int` (or `String`) and then it's checked that there is an implicit for `Int` (and no implicit for `String`).

Similarly, implicit resolution makes impact to type inference

```
trait TC[A, B]
implicit val int: TC[Int, String] = null

def foo[A, B](a: A)(implicit tc: TC[A, B]): B = ???
val x = foo(1)
// checking the type
x: String // compiles
```

Here the type `String` was inferred from the type class having the only instance.

So type inference and implicit resolution make impact to each other but are different.

If `A <: B` then `A <:< B`

```
def test[A <: B, B] = implicitly[A <:< B] // compiles
```

but if `A <:< B` then not necessarily `A <: B`

```
def checkSubtype[A <: B, B] = null

def test[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B) = checkSubtype[A, B] // doesn't compile
```

`<:` is checked by the compiler according to the spec https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance

`<:<` is just a type class

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

with the only instance

```
object <:< {
  implicit def refl[A]: A =:= A = singleton.asInstanceOf[A =:= A] // the instance
}

sealed abstract class =:=[From, To] extends (From <:< To) with Serializable
```

So `<:<` doesn't have many properties of an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory). By default there is no transitivity

```
def test[A, B, C](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< C) = implicitly[A <:< C] // doesn't compile
```

no antisymmetry

```
def test[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< A) = implicitly[A =:= B] // doesn't compile
```

no monotonicity

```
def test[A, B, F[+_]](implicit ev: A <:< B) = implicitly[F[A] <:< F[B]] // doesn't compile
```

Although starting from Scala 2.13 the following methods are defined in the standard library

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable {
  def andThen[C](r: To <:< C): From <:< C = {
    type G[-T] = T <:< C
    substituteContra[G](r)
  }

  def liftCo[F[+_]]: F[From] <:< F[To] = {
    type G[+T] = F[From] <:< F[T]
    substituteCo[G](implicitly[G[From]])
  }
}

object <:< {
  def antisymm[A, B](implicit l: A <:< B, r: B <:< A): A =:= B = singleton.asInstanceOf[A =:= B]
}
```

but they do not define implicits. So if you need these properties you can define transitivity

```
implicit def trans[A, B, C](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< C): A <:< C = ev.andThen(ev1)

def test[A, B, C](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< C) = implicitly[A <:< C] // compiles
```

Antisymmetry is trickier

```
implicit def antisym[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< A): (A =:= B) = <:<.antisymm[A, B]

def test[A, B](implicit ev2: A <:< B, ev3: B <:< A) = implicitly[A =:= B] // doesn't compile
```

If you resolve implicits manually `... = implicitly[A =:= B](antisym[A, B])`, you'll see the reason (although `implicitly[A =:= B](antisym[A, B](ev2, ev3))` works)

```
ambiguous implicit values:
 both method antisym in object App of type [A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< A): A =:= B
 and value ev2 of type A <:< B
 match expected type A <:< B
```

So you have to resolve this ambiguity prioritizing implicits. You can't decrease the priority of implicit parameter `ev2`. So you have to decrease the priority of `antisym`, which is your implicit in the current scope, you can't put it to the implicit scope (companion object etc.). The only way I found is with `shapeless.LowPriority`

```
implicit def antisym[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< A, lp: LowPriority): (A =:= B) = <:<.antisymm[A, B]

def test[A, B](implicit ev2: A <:< B, ev3: B <:< A) = implicitly[A =:= B] //  compiles
```

Similarly you can define monotonicity

```
implicit def liftCo[A, B, F[+_]](implicit ev: A <:< B): F[A] <:< F[B] = ev.liftCo[F]

def test[A, B, F[+_]](implicit ev: A <:< B) = implicitly[F[A] <:< F[B]] // compiles
def test1[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B) = implicitly[Cov[A] <:< Cov[B]] // compiles
```

But if you put all instances into the scope you'll have compile-time `Stackoverflow`

```
implicit def liftCo[A, B, F[+_]](implicit ev: A <:< B): F[A] <:< F[B] = ev.liftCo[F]
implicit def trans[A, B, C](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< C): A <:< C = ev.andThen(ev1)
implicit def antisym[A, B](implicit ev: A <:< B, ev1: B <:< A, lp: LowPriority): (A =:= B) = <:<.antisymm[A, B]

def test[A, B, F[+_]](implicit ev: A <:< B) = implicitly[F[A] <:< F[B]] // doesn't compile, Stackoverflow
```

So I guess you see why those methods are not defined as implicits by default. This would pollute the implicit scope.

More about the difference `<:` vs. `<:<` https://blog.bruchez.name/posts/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala/

Besides (compile-time) type class `<:<` there is also (runtime) method `<:<` from `scala-reflect`

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def checkSubtype[A, B]: Unit = macro checkSubtypeImpl[A, B]

def checkSubtypeImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  println(weakTypeOf[A] <:< weakTypeOf[B])
  q"()"
}
```

```
type A <: B
type B 
checkSubtype[A, B] // scalac: true    // scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
```

```
type A
type B 
checkSubtype[A, B] // scalac: false
```

Scala 2.13.10.

[Ensure arguments to generic method have same type in trait method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731176/ensure-arguments-to-generic-method-have-same-type-in-trait-method)

[What is the implicit resolution chain of `<:<`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552739/what-is-the-implicit-resolution-chain-of)

[Type parameter under self-type doesn't conform to upper bound despite evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657425/type-parameter-under-self-type-doesnt-conform-to-upper-bound-despite-evidence)

[Covariance type parameter with multiple constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996316/covariance-type-parameter-with-multiple-constraints)

[How to do type-level addition in Scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766238/how-to-do-type-level-addition-in-scala-3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849306/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209514/t-a-return-t-method https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/07/02/type_equality_to_leibniz.html https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/09/20/higher_leibniz.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019334

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `A <:< B` is an implicit conversion, it doesn't enable compiler access the knowledge that for every `A` where there is covariance `B` can be used instead, and for every `B` when there is contravariance `A` could be used.

And the value of `<:<` is provided by [`scala.<:<` companion](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/36da1b3658ddb84743ba66499a6192af7a8ff42a/src/library/scala/typeConstraints.scala) (summoning `<:<` finds `implicit def` for `=:=` and then uses variances and subtyping rules to change it into `A <:< B`), so kind of on standard library level rather than language level. So you could e.g. disable importing `scala` and provide your own things.

For informing the type system directly about type relations, you should use type bounds rather than evidence values and "generalized type bounds":

```
object CoerciveCovariance {

  trait Cov[+T]

  def cast[A, B >: A](v: Cov[A]) = {
    v: Cov[B]
  }
}
```

or if you are really interested in expanding `<:<` abilities in particular you can provide your own implicit conversion:

```
object CoerciveCovariance {

  trait Cov[+T]

  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def castF[F[+_], A, B](fa: F[A])(implicit ev: A <:< B): F[B] =
    ev.substituteCo(fa)

  def cast[A, B](v: Cov[A])(implicit
      ev: A <:< B
  ): Cov[B] = {
    v: Cov[B]
  }
}
```