# How to do type-level addition in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-level-computation, singleton-type

How can I impletement type-level operations (addition in this case) in Scala 3 ?

Here is what I would like to do (this does not compile) :

```
case class foo[S <: Int & Singleton](value: Double) {
    def bar[T <: Int & Singleton](that: foo[T]): foo[S + T] = new foo[S + T](this.value * that.value)
}

val t1 = foo[1](1.5)
val t2 = foo[1](2.0)

val t3 = t1 bar t2 //foo[2](3.0)
```

PS : the [SIP-23](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) proposal talks about libraries that implement such behaviour in Scala 2 but I am interested in Scala 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `scala.compiletime.ops.int.+`

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#the-scalacompiletimeops-package

But then you have to remove upper bound `& Singleton` for `S`

```
case class foo[S <: Int /*& Singleton*/](value: Double):
  def bar[T <: Int & Singleton](that: foo[T]): foo[S + T] =
    new foo[S + T](this.value * that.value)
```

The thing is that the `+` is defined as

```
type +[X <: Int, Y <: Int] <: Int
```

This addition is executed at compile time by the compiler but technically there is no upper bound `<: Singleton` for `S + T`.

If you really want to restore the upper bound for `S` you can replace the upper bound with generalized type constraint `<:<`

```
case class foo[S <: Int](value: Double)(using S <:< Singleton):
  def bar[T <: Int & Singleton](that: foo[T])(using (S + T) <:< Singleton): foo[S + T] =
    new foo[S + T](this.value * that.value)
```

More about the difference `<:` vs `<:<` :

[In scala 3, is it possible to make covariant/contravariant type constructor to honour coercive subtyping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762318/in-scala-3-is-it-possible-to-make-covariant-contravariant-type-constructor-to-h)

https://blog.bruchez.name/posts/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala/